# Common Lisp: Why is cl lnterning symbols to the wrong package when reading from file?

Tags: common-lisp

First, I am very new to lisp, so it is possible that I'm just missing something very obvious. That said, I have Practical Common Lisp open next to me and the CL Hyper Spec open in the next tab, and have been unable to solve this issue:

I am trying to read a tree from a file, and assign values to slots in a class using this code:

```
(defun load-char (file)
  (with-open-file (in file)
    (with-standard-io-syntax
      (let ((chr-in (read in))
            (chr (make-instance 'pc)))
        (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (setf (slot-value chr (car x)) (cdr x))) chr-in)
        chr))))
```

When I originally hacked this together and ran it under the cl-user package everything worked perfectly -- I was quite proud of myself, actually. The problem started when I packaged this along with my class definition and a few helper functions in a new package.  I loaded the package using asdf, then used `(in-package :package-name)` to change my REPL's active package.

Now when I run `(load-char "/path/to/file")` I get an error that says the `COMMON-LISP-USER::ID` (ID is the first slot in my pc class) does not exist, so I wrote this to see what I was actually getting when I read the file in:

```
(defun load-char-test (file)  
  (with-open-file (in file)  
    (with-standard-io-syntax  
      (let ((chr-in (read in))  
            (chr (make-hash-table)))  
        (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (setf (gethash (car x) chr) (cdr x))) chr-in)  
        (maphash #'(lambda (k v) (format t "~a: ~a~%" k v)) chr)
        chr))))
```

Then in the REPL I do `(defparameter hsh (load-char-test "/path/to/file"))` and everything goes without errors, and my format call returns exactly what I expect (SLOT: VALUE).  But when I do a `(gethash 'id hsh)` it returns `NIL  NIL`.  But, when I do `(gethash 'common-lisp-user::id hsh)` it returns the expected value.

So, I'm reading in everything just fine, but everything in my list is being interned under the COMMON-LISP-USER package instead of the one I defined, and I cannot figure out why.  Help is greatly appreciated.

P.S. Sorry if this post is needlessly long, I just wanted to show that I had actually tried to figure this out myself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Symbols created by `READ` are interned in the package that is the *current* value of `*PACKAGE*` at runtime, not the value `*PACKAGE*` had when the code that calls `READ` was defined. One option, then, is to wrap your reading forms in a form that binds `*PACKAGE*`, e.g.

```
(let ((*package* (find-package :package-name)))
  ...)
```

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://pastebin.com/e0xmUAmp .  It is still interning under cl-user.

Comment: @oobivat: see my answer. The LET needs to be inside the macro WITH-STANDARD-IO-SYNTAX.

Answer (score 10):

Note that `WITH-STANDARD-IO-SYNTAX` binds the variable `*PACKAGE*` to the package `CL-USER`.

You need to bind the variable `*PACKAGE*` inside that macro using `LET` to the package you wish to use.

Note also that `WITH-STANDARD-IO-SYNTAX` binds the variable `*READ-EVAL*` to `T`. Which for security reasons usually is not what one might want as default. Again, change that via a `LET` binding.