# Changing hunchentoot's current package

Tags: package, common-lisp

I've set up a hunchentoot project with quickproject per Xach's [instructions.](http://xach.livejournal.com/278047.html) In-package is run at the top of the file, and hunchentoot is started later in the file. The REPL is switched to my package also, but it is evident that hunchentoot is not running in my package. This causes some disparity between tests in the REPL and the browser. For example there is a function that looks up some stuff in an alist, but hunchentoot gets NILs from it because it is using symbols from another package.

I am aware from the answers to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081399/common-lisp-why-is-cl-lnterning-symbols-to-the-wrong-package-when-reading-from) that I can wrap every piece of code that interns symbols in something like

```
(let ((*package* (find-package :package-name)))
  ...)
```

which will set the `*package*` var to the correct package for the duration of the enclosed code.

Putting this in every function that needs it feels to me like a messy hack.

Intuition says that I should be able to start hunchentoot like this:

```
(let ((*package* (find-package :package-name)))
  (hunchentoot:start (make-instance 'hunchentoot:easy-acceptor :port 4242)))
```

So that it makes its whole run with `*package*` set to the value that I prefer, thereby ensuring that any interning done by a call from the webserver is done in my package. It doesn't work. Hunchentoot ends up interning things under cl-user, possibly due to using a macro like WITH-STANDARD-IO-SYNTAX as in the link above.

Even if I can persuade hunchentoot to do what I want, is there a reason why my 'messy hack' is still the better thing to do?

Comment: You better show the specific piece of code where a symbol is not found.  When used in the common way, packages never get in your way.

Comment: I'm not sure that showing code is going to make things clear. At least I can't think of any piece of my code that would do so. Maybe I should step back and figure out exactly what I am trying to ask. Right now it seems to be a rather vague "Why doesn't it do what I want?" But thanks for your help, guys. You did make some things clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Hunchentoot runs in multi-threaded, its acceptors and handlers are processed in child threads made with `bordeaux-threads` on non-Lispwork CL implementation. The reason of the situation you asked is that the current packages of child threads become `COMMON-LISP-USER`.

To get the result you want, you can make child threads' current packages same as calling thread's with implementing `START-THREAD` generic function corresponding to `ONE-THREAD-PER-CONNECTION-TASKMASTER` taskmaster.

Note that you use latest Hunchentoot which has `START-THREAD` generic function, I use of version 1.2.19.

```
(in-package :hunchentoot)

(defmethod start-thread ((taskmaster one-thread-per-connection-taskmaster) thunk &key name)
  (let* (;; calling thread's current package
         (package-name (package-name *package*))
         ;; initial special bindings passed to bordeaux threads
         (initial-bindings `((*package* . (find-package ,package-name)))))
    ;; making child thread passing initial special bindings
    (bt:make-thread thunk :name name :initial-bindings initial-bindings)))
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not a Hunchentoot specific question, but relates to Common Lisp packages in general.

What you are seeing is that in your code, the `*PACKAGE*` special variable is not bound to your own package.  `IN-PACKAGE` changes `*PACKAGE*` only at compile and read time.  When a function in your package is called at run time, `*PACKAGE*` is not re-bound and needs to be bound explicitly.

When you are using `INTERN` or `FIND-SYMBOL`, it is often best to specify the package as argument.  Alternatively, you can bind `*PACKAGE*` yourself.

Try `LOAD`ing this file to see:

```
(defpackage :foo
  (:use :cl))

(in-package :foo)

(defun test ()
  (print *package*))

(in-package :cl-user)

(foo::test)
```

Comment: So evidently hunchentoot is setting ```*package*``` back to cl-user? Or did it never 'inherit' the ```*package*``` that I set? My REPL, running in the same process as hunchentoot, has ```*package*``` set to <mypackage>. Does each thread have its own copy of ```*package*```?

Comment: Hunchentoot is not setting ```*package*```.  Package is just a special variable that can has a global binding and that can be bound anywhere in the call chain.  You may want to review the "Variables" chapter in PCL, in particular the section on special variables (http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/variables.html)

Answer (score 3):

Common Lisp code does not 'run' in a package.

There are a few operations which use a default package. Like reading a symbol from a text stream:

```
CL-USER 1 > *package*
#<The COMMON-LISP-USER package, 56/64 internal, 0/4 external>

CL-USER 2 > (read-from-string "FOO")
FOO
3

CL-USER 3 > (describe (read-from-string "FOO"))

FOO is a SYMBOL
NAME          "FOO"
VALUE         #<unbound value>
FUNCTION      #<unbound function>
PLIST         NIL
PACKAGE       #<The COMMON-LISP-USER package, 57/64 internal, 0/4 external>
```

or like finding a symbol:

```
(find-symbol "FOO")
```

These operations depend on the value of the variable `cl:*package*`.

To make sure that these operations (reading symbols, finding symbols, interning symbols, ...) are doing what you expect, you may want to:

- set or bind the `*package*` variable to the package you want to
- explicitly pass the package to operations. You can call `(find-symbol "FOO")` and have `*package*` set to some package. But you can also call `(find-symbol "FOO" my-package)` by passing the respective package as an argument.

**Summary**: Common Lisp code does not 'run in a package', but it uses the variable `*package*` as a default package for package-related operations. You need to set or bind this variable when you use this mechanism.